# WP_Query в аргументах мета поле с массивом

Tags: php, wordpress

Речь о произвольном типе постов.
Есть переменная, содержащая некое число, например

```
$numb = '5';
```

Есть мета поле, которое содержит вот такой массив:

```
a:2:{s:4:"name";s:16:"Тестовый";s:2:"id";s:1:"3";}
```

В этом массиве интересует только **ID**, который в данном примере равен **3**.

Необходимо построить WP_Query, в аргументах которого получить мета поле и сравнить **ID** из него со значением из параметра `$numb`. Соответственно, включать в цикл только те посты, у которых значение из параметра `$numb` будет равно **id** из массива этого мета поля.

Comment: Я подозревал.  
Значит буду думать, как можно это по-другому сделать.

Comment: @KAGGDesign А вообще wp_query умеет с метаполями, содержащими массив работать?

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: @KAGGDesign так, значит пришли к выводу, что можно попробовать regexp использоваться, чтобы вычленить нужное из массива. С регуляркой дружу плохо, пока только смог все цифры из строки выделить, а надо найти id, после пропустить знаки ";s: после любое количество цифр, после знаки :" и наконец искомое любое количество цифр. Сложно...

Comment: Да в том-то и дело, что сложно

Comment: @KAGGDesign кажется получилось `(id";s:[0-9]+:")[0-9]+(";)` в коде на месте второго отрывка `[0-9]+` нужно будет вставлять переменную `$numb`. Можете показать как регулярку в мета поле аргумента wp_query использовать. На каме посмотрел документацию, как-то не очень...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80221/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-aaron).

Comment: @KAGGDesign удалось. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решение! Не могу сказать, насколько правильное регулярное выражение получилось, но работает.

Итак, в параметрах **WP_Query** при работе с мета полями используем `meta_query`, который содержит параметр `compare` (вариант сравнения). В параметре `compare` необходимо указать вид сравнения - **REGEXP** .

Соответственно, получаем такого вида аргумент для произвольного поля, содержащего массив:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'AND ',
    array(
        'key' => 'ИМЯ ПОЛЯ',
        'value' => '(id";s:[0-9]+:")' . $ПЕРЕМЕННАЯ . '(";})$',
        'compare' => 'REGEXP'
    )
)
```

Выражаю благодарность **KAGG Design** за подсказку по поводу REGEXP.